# LoadError: cannot load such file (Rake Task)

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5.2

What is the correct way to reference a `require` in Ruby on Rails?

error:

> > LoadError: cannot load such file 'lib/appname/loader/model_import'

Rake Task:

```
require 'csv'
require 'lib/appname/loader/model_import'

namespace :app_name do
  namespace :loader do

    desc "Loads data into Database"

    task model_import: :environment  do

      include AppName::Loader::ModelImport
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4):

`require` is used to import a library or module that has been installed properly.
If you're trying to access something in the same directory or internal to a library or project, then try using `require_relative`